# Istanbul lcov report missing tests

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm running mocha with istanbul, es6 and babel. When I run my npm script

```
"test-coverage-client": "istanbul cover .mocha \"./client/**/*.test.{jsx,js}\" -- --compilers js:babel-core/register --require setup.js ",
```

I see all the unit tests ran and I get the Coverage Summary, but my lcov-report index file is missing a bunch of unit tests. Any clues on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Its old but thought its worth sharing the answer. I also had the same problem and was able to find a way to include all the test source files with the parameter "--include-all-sources".